# Java comment for getter and setter method

Tags: java, comments

my question is should i comment like following:

```
/**
     * Getter for {@link #auto_key}
     * @return {@link #auto_key}
     */
    public String getAuto_key() {
        return auto_key;
    }
    /**
     * Setter for {@link #auto_key}
     * @param auto_key the {@link #auto_key} to set
     */
    public void setAuto_key(String auto_key) {
        this.auto_key = auto_key;
    }
```

basically i want to ask, using {@link} in comment for getter and setter method is correct? or should i use normal comment without using {@link} ?
and this way is a java standard or not ?

Answer (score 10):

Actually, I deliberately don't javadoc getters and setters, because you aren't adding any value by doing so - they are what they are... accessor methods. In fact, you would be creating a kind of code bloat by adding javadoc to them.

I only put javadoc on non-getter/setters.

Comment: I agree that documenting "X getter " for `getX()` would be useless. It might be interesting to document why "X" should be used, though.

Comment: @eric I would argue that if you need to document what a field is you haven’t named it well enough. What a getter returns should be completely obvious. Using Lombok (and you’d be mad not to) doesn’t allow for any javadoc on accessors, which means you have to name fields well.

Comment: Not "what" a setter is, but "why" it should be set to this or that value. I'll take a serious look at Lombok, thanks.

Comment: @eric what do you mean by *why*? There is no “why” to a setter; you’re just assigning a value to a field. eg the *why* of calling `customer.setName("John Smith");` is “I want to set the customer’s name to John Smith”. If you are alluding to documenting the *effect* of setting a field to a particular value, eg `car.setCruiseControlKph(100)`, again the name of the field should tell you the effect of setting it to a particular value. If you want to add meaning to the *value*, use a well named enum or a parameter object. I stand by my belief that accessors should never need javadoc.

Comment: Yes, something like `car.setCruiseControlKph(100)`. We work with relatively complex simulation models for buildings and energy systems. Units can be much longer than just `km/h` so I'd like to write them in documentation and not append them in each field. I'd also like to add references to papers when needed. For enums, even if they have clear names, it might be worth it to specify why one should be preferred over the other (e.g. one is fast, the other is more accurate but might have to run overnight). I do agree that it would be noise to document every setter.

Comment: @eric for values that need units, you can have two parameters; one for the amount and one for an enum of the units, eg `car.setCruiseControl(100, KPH)` but the units enum may have MPH, MPS etc too. This of course makes it more than a simple setter, but the API is clearer. See Java’s TimeUnit class for examples of methods with unit parameters.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. `car.setCruiseControl(100, KPH)` is nice indeed for a written API. Some of our models are called from a JavaFX interface, with setters and getters automatically converted to textfields, dropdown menus or radio buttons. I'm looking for a way to automate the documentation for those controls.

Comment: @eric consider using an annotation on the getter (or the field if using lombok)

Comment: A few weeks later: we're using resource bundles and property files for the fields, which will be used in GUI tooltips and PDF documents. Thanks for the interesting discussion.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would suggest generating stand-alone documentation for your set/get methods, while still using `{@link}`, that is to do both. This way, when the field is accessible people can still get to its documentation. If afterwards it becomes private due to a refactoring, you won't end-up with a bunch of incomplete Javadocs that need to be modified as well.
2. While documentation for setter/getter methods may seem like code bloat, I would still suggest creating it for a couple of reasons:

   - It gives you a standard location to mention important information, such as setter arguments that should not be `null` or getters that are woefully inefficient in a particular implementation of an interface.
   - It does not assume that the reader automatically knows what the backing field does. Sure, `setLength()` may be descriptive enough in some contexts, but what exactly does `setLimit()` do?
   - It does not assume that there *is* a backing field, or that the get/set methods are only doing just that in a particular implementation. It is an unfortunate reality that when refactoring is constrained by compatibility concerns, various artifacts are left behind. E.g. `setLimit()` could delegate to `setSizeLimit()`, which is something that should be noted.
   - It removes any and all ambiguity. What you consider to be common-sense may not be straight-forward for all people. Without documentation various assumptions will be made that may or may not be true. For example, in a list implementation, does `setLength(0)` also set all contained references to `null` or not?
   - Most importantly, it allows the Javadoc policy to boil-down to a simple "document everything everywhere". Having a policy with various exceptions, on the other hand, will inevitably lead to laxness and code that is eventually left undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

Matter of convention. Varies organization to organization. Previously, we were asked not bother commenting on getters and setters as long as it is obvious what it does. Which is same as comments without `{@link}`.

Currently, we add `{@link}` as codes written earlier already has this convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you can refer in your documentation to `#auto_key` using the `{@link}`, it means the variable is public accessible (otherwise, the link would not resolve in the javadoc). This means the getter and setter are redundant.

I would strongly recommend to make your `auto_key` field private and keep the getter and setter. Then adjust the name of the getter and setter to match Java conventions (`autoKey`, `setAutoKey`, `getAutoKey` ). And consider firing `PropertyChangeEvent`s when the `autoKey` is changed (as a getter/setter combination typically suggests - see [JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) ).

As for your documentation: it adds nothing new to what the name of the method already suggests. So I would remove it, or add some extra documentation on what the `autoKey` exactly does (which is not clear to me from the snippet), whether it may be set to `null`, ... .

Answer (score 0):

You should not put any comments describing getters or setters, unless the method looks like one, but encapsulated different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Accessors and mutators are generic methods in classes where the notion of encapsulation is applied (i.e. having private instance attributes). *This is why in some IDEs like Netbeans for example, they can even be generated automatically.*

Also, their names, according to conventions, are quite explicit about what they do and thus allow to distinguish them from other methods more specific to business needs.

**All this to say that they do not need to be documented.**

> Of course, if in the context of your application you add a particular instruction in >your setter for example, in relation to your needs and the logic of your program, in my >opinion, nothing prevents you from adding a descriptive comment line to it